# How to make Rhythmbox dark?

Tags: 20.04, themes, music, rhythmbox

I am new here and I would like to know if there is any way to make the Rhythmbox music player dark.

Thank you for your support guys.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the <kbd>≡</kbd> icon on the top right and then *Preferences* → *Plugins* → *Alternative Toolbar*  → *Preferences* and select *Dark theme if available*.

You need to restart the player after that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Rhythmbox does not provide an option to use a dark theme, however, in general, you can (unofficially) run an application with the specified theme by assigning a theme to the `GTK_THEME` variable as follows:

```
GTK_THEME=<theme-name> <application>
```

where `<theme-name>` is the name of the theme you want to use for the application and `<application>` is the application you want to run.

For example, if you use Yaru as your main theme, but want Rhythmbox to use the dark version of Yaru, you run:

```
GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark rhythmbox
```

To make Rhythmbox use this theme when you run it from its launcher, run the following commands:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
sed -i 's/Exec=rhythmbox %U/Exec=bash -c "GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark rhythmbox" %U/' ~/.local/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop
```

- The first command copies the `rhythmbox.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`
- The second command changes the command that executes `rhythmbox` from `rhythmbox %U` to `bash -c "GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark rhythmbox" %U` in the `~/.local/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop` file.

  Here you may replace the `Yaru-dark` theme with the dark theme you would like to use.

Comment: Thanks so much! My eyes are saved. I use Fedora 37/Gnome, the desktop file path was slightly different: /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Rhythmbox3.desktop